# MVC3 and validating a mixture of Razor and jQuery plugins

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-tokeninput

I am using MVC3 and my view has a mixture of razor and raw html in my view e.g.

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PAGE)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PAGE)
</div>


<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PERIODICAL)
</div>
     div class="editor-field">
     <div class="editor-field">
          <input type="text" id="periodicallist" name="tiperiodical" />
     </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript applies the tokenInput control plugin to the textbox and its all fine, but I wonder how I can validate this (i.e. for empty textbox/tokenInput), it needs to filled with at least 1 token.  At the moment it's confusing having these two forms of creating a view, letting Razor constuct elements direct from the model, and then adding more complexity/cusomization by usin jQuery plugins etc.

Can anyone advise how I can validate jQuery plugins on posting back to the controller?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using unobtrusive validation then you all have to do is add the necessary HTML5 data attributes to the input elements from javascript and microsoft's unobtrusive javascript library will take care of the rest.

For ex. if you have dynamically injected a textbox into the form through javascript and you need to perform required validation then all you have to add the `data-val` and `data-val-required` attributes as below.

```
<input data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="No. of joinees is required" 
       name="NoOfJoinees" 
       type="text"  />
```

EDIT:

To display the validation error message you have to inject a `span` near to the field,

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" 
      data-valmsg-for="NoOfJoinees" 
      data-valmsg-replace="true">
</span>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Mark, have just done what you said - but it kind of half works - in that the form will stop from posting, but you don't get any nice error message like with the other MVC framework "out of the box" error messages.  Something I might be missing here?

Comment: fantastic! Kind of obvious now.  Thanks very much for you help. :)